# Need to use only the emulator of android studio, so i don't need to load any projects

Tags: android, ubuntu, emulator

i need to use only the emulator without loading any project or other things. Is there a way maybe a terminal command to run it without opening Android studio and load a project. I'm using ubuntu

Comment: IIRC yes it runs via `kvm` virtualization on *nix and I know you can launch just the emulator but I'm at work so I can't access my system to check how.  I'd also say you should ask over on superuser.com since your question is OT for here.